# IOS- How to execute function after segue finishes in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

How would I execute a specific function after a segue has finished loading in objective-c?

Comment: what do you mean by  "segue has finished loading"?

Comment: Like after it transitions from one screen to another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post-segue function calls are most easily put in the `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()` functions of the target view controller subclass.

Comment: is there a way I can all the viewDidLoad() of another class from a different class through code, and not the story board?

Comment: viewDidLoad is a UIViewControllerDelegate function. It gets called by the system when the view controller completes loading. User does not call this directly.

Comment: I want to do edit core data in the background, and the previous code executes when viewDidLoad() runs, can I replicate this without changing screens? (since its in the background)

Comment: iOS background execution is a little more complicated, you'll need to start a background task in 'applicationDidEnterBackground', there's plenty of posts on this ... Maybe you just want to do the CoreData editing in a different thread? so as to not block the UI instead?

Comment: yeah, I'm doing it in a different thread, can I just copy the code in the viewDidLoad() into another function, and just call the new function from my other class?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can move the CoreData save edit code to an action or anyplace else. Tip: I use class UIManagedDocument for all my CoreData models. It handles the threading and contexts, so I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a delegate callback with `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Then when under `didShowViewController` notification you can put your custom function, etc.

You could also theoretically track the segues in `AppDelegate`, and dispatch functions from there.

You have a few options!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your methods by overriding `viewDidDisappear()` method of `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol

Implement the protocol method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

This will trigger, when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.